# grid view position 0 cannot be updated

Tags: android, gridview

I have gridview and the number of cells are around 42 (7*6). -- It's a calendar.

I want to select multiple cells in gridview with following gesture :
1) long click on position 0 -> change color of position 0. 
2) then, drag to position 10 -> change colors of all cells located between position 0 and position 10. (cell color of postion 0, 1, 2... and 10 should be changed)

I implemented this with following way :
1) add a framelayout to each cell
2) implement the gesture and call setforeground of the framelayout during dragging.

This way works and I can see the color of the all cells are changed.

However, although I call setforeground of position 0, it does not change. 
color of only cell position 0 is not changed.

I saw many questions about position 0 of grid view.

In summary, setforground of framelayout in position 0 does not work. 
If you have another solution to implement my scenario, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug in GridView because setforeground does not work in position 0.

Alternatively, I made 7*6 cells using LinearLayout, instead of GridView. 
Then, the setforeground is working in the LinearLayout.